# GL_QUAD draws triangle

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to fill quad that is generated by 4 lines with `GL_LINES`. However, when I try to fill the quad it only fills with triangle. This is the code that draws the lines:

```
def SurfaceContour(self, vertices, edges):
     glBegin(GL_LINES)
     for edge in edges:
         for vertex in edge:
             glColor3fv((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
             glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
     glEnd()
```

This is the code that draws fills the quad:

```
def Surfaces(self,  vertices):
     glBegin(GL_QUADS)
     for i in range(4):
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 0.3)
        glVertex3fv(vertices[i ,:])
     glEnd()
```

This is the vertices matrix that I pass into:

```
[[   0.    -20.23    7.  ]
 [   0.    -20.23   -7.  ]
 [ 100.    -10.      5.  ]
 [ 100.    -10.     -5.  ]]
```

[image: This is the result that i get:]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of this vertices

```
[[   0.    -20.23    7.  ]
 [   0.    -20.23   -7.  ]
 [ 100.    -10.      5.  ]
 [ 100.    -10.     -5.  ]]
```

is like this:

[image]

If you want to draw the quad which is defined by the 4 vertices, then you have either to draw a `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`:

[image]

```
def Surfaces(self,  vertices):
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
    for i in range(4):
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 0.3)
    glVertex3fv(vertices[i ,:])
    glEnd()
```

Or you have to change the order of the vertices, that it matches  the requiremts for a `GL_QUAD`:

[image]

```
[[   0.    -20.23    7.  ]
 [   0.    -20.23   -7.  ]
 [ 100.    -10.     -5.  ]
 [ 100.    -10.      5.  ]]
```

See further [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive)

Comment: Thanks so much, that works flawlessly. Just one follow up question, After the surface colored, if I rotate the view, the back side of the surface doesn't look like colored. [Example View](https://ibb.co/i60L76), do you have any idea about this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BjkOcean Maybe it is an [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) issue. Try `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)` or do not switch face culling on.

Answer (score 1):

At first you are using old deprecated api, neither glBegin/glEnd and GL_QUAD should not be used in modern applications.

Second, glVertex3fv receives array to one element, in your code you pass `glVertex3fv(vertices[i ,:])` slice of original array, in fact only first element is used, so it is equal to `verticies[i]`. This lead to incorrect order of verticies for GL_QUAD. You have to change primitive type or elements order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please provide a small example of how should I set the code for modern OpenGL application.

Comment: @BjkOcean It is not so easy, main point here is to use data buffers, instead of many calls  `glVertex`. It's better for you to google some tutorial targeting modern opengl (version 3+). Like this for example: https://learnopengl.com/